# Django models.ForeignKey issue with model with custom foreign key

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I use Django 1.11, Python 3.6 and PostgreSQL 9.6.
I define two models as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

```
class CircDetect(models.Model):
    oid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'circdetect'


class PatientMed(models.Model):
    ...
    circdetect = models.ForeignKey(CircDetect, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='oid')
    ...
```

But when I try to get an access to the list of PatientMed objects on the admin site I get an exception:

> ProgrammingError at /canreg/editor/patientmed/ 
>   column patient_med.circdetect_id does not exist 
>  
>   LINE 1: ... "patient_info"."id") INNER JOIN "circdetect" ON ("patient_m...
>   HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "patient_med.circdetect".

It looks like Django tries to get `id` filed of `circdetect`, which is actually has name `oid`.

What can I do to fix this issue?

**EDITED on 21 jul**

As Ahmad took note below, I have an another model, that I didn't mention. I'm not sure it affects on the error in this case but this is that model:

```
class PatientInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'patient_info'
```

And PatientMed is connected with PatientInfo this way:

```
class PatientMed(models.Model):
    info = models.OneToOneField(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

But it works without any problems.

I should say, that `circdetect` is a legacy table, that I already had in my database when I started work.

**EDITED**

I use this code to show PatientMed objects in the admin site:

```
class PatientMedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'info',
        ...
        'circdetect',
        ...
    )
    list_per_page = 25

admin.site.register(models.PatientMed, PatientMedAdmin)
```

**EDITED**

As Alasdair ask below I put here full models. There is no secret in them, but they are big

```
class CircDetect(models.Model):
    oid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    txt = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'circdetect'
        ordering = ['code']


class PatientInfo(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    home_phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (to_str(self.last_name), to_str(self.first_name),
                                 to_str(self.patronymic), to_str(self.birth_date))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'patient_info'


class PatientMed(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    info = models.OneToOneField(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    center = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fddate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    tsdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    tdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    edate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    otcode = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True)
    ddate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    death_icd = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    ecode = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    esource = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dcause = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dsource = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    numtumor = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    iccc = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    icd_10 = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    icd_o = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    fds = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    circdetect = models.ForeignKey(to=CircDetect, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='oid')
    hyst = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    cyto = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    exp_oper = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    immun = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    cytogen = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    lab_instr = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    incentr = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    lasttest = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    lastsource = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lfudate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    lfucode = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    otregion = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    date_actend = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    concord = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    protocol = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    autopsie = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    tabort = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stage = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stage_sym = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    chirurg = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    radiolog = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    chimio = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    rdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    rem = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    t_tnm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    n_tnm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    m_tnm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    g_tnm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    encr_bas = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ct_tnm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cn_tnm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cm_tnm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    land = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lum = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    oss = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    hepar = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    lung = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    brain = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    skin = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    nephro = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    herm = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    periton = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    kmark = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    unknown = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    other = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    acc = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'patient_med'
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Did you create a migration and run it?

Comment: Yes, I run python manage.py makemigrations <projectname>, and then  python manage.py migrate.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have to specify [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-column), to let Django know the name of the column in the `PatientMed` column.

```
class PatientMed(models.Model):
    circdetect = models.ForeignKey(CircDetect, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='circdetect', to_field='oid')
```

Comment: If I specify `db_column='circdetect'` I have no exception, but also I have no rows when I open my list view with PatientMed objects on the admin site.

Comment: It's hard to tell why it's not working, because you haven't shown the complete models. Sometimes the Django admin can swallow errors and show blank results rather than an error. You could try experimenting adding/removing items from the `PatientMedAdmin` to see whether you can make the objects appear/disappear. You could also try `PatientMed.objects.all()` and `PatientMed.objects.select_related('circdetect')` in the shell to see whether you get results.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair, I'll check it. I've added my full models in the question. I didn't add them early because they are too huge.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written the instruction that makes the error. But it seems that you have another table named PatientInfo that the error is related to.

Comment: Yes Ahmad, I have that model. I've edited my question and added a description of them.

Comment: And let me know the ORM command you have written to get an access to the list of PatientMed objects. @AlexP

Comment: I'm new in Django and not sure which command you mean. Sorry. I use PatientMed objects in the admin site only. I've edited my question and added the code how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the cause of the problem. I solved it by dropping my database and recreating it and my entities.
Thank you everyone.